# Customising southall chapter style

Tags: memoir, appendices

I am using southall chapter style for a book. However, I need to customize it so that it shows "Appendix A", etc for appendices rather than just "A", etc. That is, the chapter numbers for the main chapters should remain as they are, but for appendix, they should be preceded by the label Appendix.

My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\chapterstyle{southall}
\renewcommand\cftappendixname{\appendixname~}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{Preface}
\lipsum[1]

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{Extra material at the back}
\lipsum[1]

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And where can this style be found?

Comment: It is a part of memoir. In memoir.cls. Sorry, stackexchange removed some lines from my MWE. Have added them back.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know memoir at all. You might try looking at the `appendix` package (same author as memoir, I believe), which has chances to be compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it: the idea is to define an `appsouthall` variant of the original `southall` style and then use the `etoolbox` package so the new style is used inside the `appendices` environment.

The code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\chapterstyle{southall}
\renewcommand\cftappendixname{\appendixname~}

\newlength\AppWd
\settowidth\AppWd{\chapnumfont\appendixname}

\makechapterstyle{appsouthall}{%
  \chapterstyle{southall}
  \addtolength{\midchapskip}{-\AppWd}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t][\baselineskip][b]{\dimexpr\beforechapskip+\AppWd\relax}
      {\vspace{0pt}\chapnumfont%%%\figureversion{lining}
                   \appendixname~\thechapter}
    \end{minipage}}%
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{\chapterstyle{appsouthall}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{Preface}
\lipsum[1]

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{Extra material at the back}
\lipsum[1]

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]